# tsconfig path cannot be found

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, tsconfig

I am working on a nodejs app and I want to configure my path in tsconfig.json but I am having issues with the path configuration I keep getting an error `Error: Cannot find module '@environment'`. what could be the issue?

tsconfig

```
  {
    "compilerOptions": {
      "resolveJsonModule" : true,
      "target": "es6",
      "module": "commonjs" ,
      "lib": [
        "dom",
        "es6"
      ],
      "outDir": "build",
      "rootDir": "src",
      "removeComments": true ,
      "strict": true,
      "noImplicitAny": true,
      "baseUrl": "./",
      "paths": {
        "@lime/*": ["src/*"],
        "@environment": ["src/config/environment.ts"],
      },
      "esModuleInterop": true 
    }
  }
```

Project tree:

```
src - config - environment.ts
    ...
    - index.js
package.json
tsconfig.json
...
```

environment.ts

```
import * as dotenv from 'dotenv';

dotenv.config();

interface Environment {
    port: number | string,
    baseUrl: string,
    databaseUri: string,
}

export const environment: Environment = {
    port: process.env.PORT!,
    baseUrl: process.env.BASE_URL!,
    databaseUri: process.env.DATABASE_URI!
}
```

in `index.ts` i imported environment.ts as `import { environment } from '@environment';` please what could be wrong?

Comment: Could you add the file that is giving your problem and a tree representation of the project folder?

Comment: @leonardfactory i have added the folder representation and the envirionment.ts file

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to execute this directly with `node` or `ts-node`, you should be aware that `tsconfig` paths are not resolved by default by node. If you are using `tsc` for the build (and not webpack or similar to generate a bundle), you can add to your dependencies [`tsconfig-paths`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/tsconfig-paths) like this:

```
npm install --save tsconfig-paths
```

And then execute the code with:

```
node -r tsconfig-paths/register dist/index.js
```

If you are using TS code directly with `ts-node`, you can use:

```
ts-node -r tsconfig-paths/register src/index.ts
```

In production is suggested instead to bundle the source with webpack for example, and use a plugin like [`tsconfig-paths-webpack-plugin)`](https://github.com/dividab/tsconfig-paths-webpack-plugin) to resolve paths while bundling.

Answer (score 1):

I may not sure, i check the documentation. Seems like paths should be dir. please try this combination.

```
{

      "baseUrl": "./",
      "paths": {
        "@lime/*": ["src/*"],
        "@environment": ["src/config/"],
      },
      "esModuleInterop": true 
    }
  }
```

and import like:

`import { environment } from '@environment/environment'`

Answer (score 0):

tsconfig.json

```
// prettier-ignore
{
  "extends": "@tsconfig/react-native/tsconfig.json",     /* Recommended React Native TSConfig base */
  "compilerOptions": {
    /* Visit https://aka.ms/tsconfig.json to read more about this file */

    /* Completeness */
    "skipLibCheck": true,                                 /* Skip type checking all .d.ts files. */

    /* Path */
    "baseUrl": "./src",
    "paths": {
      "@/*": ["./*"],
      "@assets/*": ["assets/*"],
      "@components/*": ["components/*"],
      "@hooks/*": ["hooks/*"],
      "@lib/*": ["lib/*"],
      "@ui/*": ["ui/*"],
    }
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "babel.config.js",
    "metro.config.js",
    "jest.config.js"
  ]
}
```

babel.config.js

```
module.exports = {
  presets: ['module:metro-react-native-babel-preset'],
  plugins: [
    [
      'module-resolver',
      {
        root: ['./src'],
        extensions: [
          '.ios.ts',
          '.android.ts',
          '.ts',
          '.ios.tsx',
          '.android.tsx',
          '.tsx',
          '.jsx',
          '.js',
          '.json',
        ],
        alias: {
          '@': './src',
          '@assets': './src/assets',
          '@components': './src/components',
          '@hooks': './src/hooks',
          '@lib': './src/lib',
          '@ui': './src/ui',
        },
      },
    ],
  ],
};
```